# List styling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, list

I want to style a list using JavaScript to add a class to the active firstlevel list-item. So if you click 'Flyer', `<li><a href="#">Downloads &raquo;</a>` becomes `<li class="active"><a href="#">Downloads &raquo;</a>`.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navmenu">
  <li><a href="#">Downloads &raquo;</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="downloads_flyer.php">Flyer</a></li>
      <li><a href="downloads_jahresberichte.php">Jahresberichte</a></li>
      <li><a href="downloads_banner.php">Banner</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="presse.php">Pressecenter</a></li>
  <li><a href="kontakt.php">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JAVASCRIPT (updated)**

```
var i = 0;
var url = "<?php echo end(explode("/", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])); ?>";
var liste = document.getElementById("navmenu").getElementsByTagName("li");
while(i < liste.length) {
    var topList = liste[i];
    var topLink = liste[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (topLink.href.substr((topLink.href.length - 1), 1) != "#"  // To avoid matching the 'Downloads' link.
     && topLink.href.indexOf(url) > 0)
    {
        topList.className = "active";
    }
    i++;
}
```

As you can see it adds 'active' to the LI containing the link but it should be added to the toplevel LI.
How can I get the script running correctly - what is my mistake?

**Final Solution**

```
var i = 0;
var url = "<?php echo end(explode("/", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])); ?>";
var liste = document.getElementById("navmenu").getElementsByTagName("li");
while(i < liste.length) {
    var topLink = liste[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (topLink.href.substr((topLink.href.length - 1), 1) != "#"  // To avoid matching the 'Downloads' link.
     && topLink.href.indexOf(url) > 0)
    {
        if(topLink.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.tagName == "LI") {
            topLink.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = "active";
        } else {
            topLink.parentNode.className = "active";
        }
    }

    i++;
}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: you never increase the value of 'i'

Comment: you don't increment i, so the loop runs forever?

Comment: The external div should be a ul to have li children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to increment you var `i`. Your while enters on an infinite loop! Intead of use `document.URL`, try using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`:

```
var i = 0;
var url = "<?php echo end(explode("/", $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"])); ?>";
var liste = document.getElementById("navmenu").getElementsByTagName("li");
while(i < liste.length) {
    var topLink = liste[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (topLink.href.substr((topLink.href.length - 1), 1) != "#"  // To avoid matching the 'Downloads' link.
     && topLink.href.indexOf(url) > 0)
    {
        topLink.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.className = "active";
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: save code `while(i < liste.length) liste[++i].className = "active";` ;)

Comment: @Hannes Yeah but I doesn't like this way of codding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you're right but I still need help with that function. I updated my question.

Comment: @manticore I'm editing my answer, are you using some server-side language(PHP, ASP or JSP) that you can use on this script ?

Comment: Yes, I can use PHP. By the way can I use liste[i] instead of liste.item(n) in plain JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks Marcio, your code works fine but it classifies the links not the listitems. I need the toplevel LI's to be 'active' (even if they have children), so I can style the list as intended.

Comment: Thanks Márcio! I only had to add another if-clause and it worked fine!